# How to convert string to a datetime in PHP for SQL Server

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save some records in SQL Server using PHP and Laravel and CSV files, in csv files I have a date with format 'D. d M. Y, g:i:s A', like 'lun. 08 ene. 2024, 1:54:02 p. m.' and I need to convert it into 'Y-m-d H:i:s', but it just return this '1970-01-01 00:00:00' when I use just

i'd tried using date and strtotime like this:

```php
<?php
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('mon. 08 jan. 2024, 1:54:02 p. m.'));

echo $newDate;
?>
```

Comment: That date string [works for me](https://3v4l.org/9DuVC), your issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: @aynber I see it, but csv is in spanish, so it apears like 'lun. 08 ene. 2024, 1:54:02 p. m.', that's why it doesn't work

Comment: It helps if you specify the exact string that's not working, instead of the translated string. You'll either need to set the locale so that strtotime knows it's working with Spanish instead of English, or use the DateTime class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first replacing Spanish day and month names with their English counterparts using `str_replace`. Then, `DateTime::createFromFormat` should be used to parse this adjusted string into a `DateTime` object according to the specified format. And then, the format method of the DateTime object is used to convert the date into the desired `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format. Hope this helps

```
$dateStr = 'lun. 08 ene. 2024, 1:54:02 p. m.';
$dateStr = str_replace(['ene.', 'lun.'], ['Jan.', 'Mon.'], $dateStr); // Replace Spanish abbreviations with English

$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('D. d M. Y, g:i:s a', $dateStr);
$newDate = $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom method for date conversion:

```
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    public function getConvertDate($date)
    {

        $monthTranslations = [
            'ene' => 'jan',
            'feb' => 'feb',
            'mar' => 'mar',
            'abr' => 'apr',
            'may' => 'may',
            'jun' => 'jun',
            'jul' => 'jul',
            'ago' => 'aug',
            'sep' => 'sep',
            'oct' => 'oct',
            'nov' => 'nov',
            'dic' => 'dec',
        ];

        $translatedDate = strtr($date, array_merge(['lun' => 'Mon', 'mar' => 'Tue', 'mié' => 'Wed', 'jue' => 'Thu', 'vie' => 'Fri', 'sáb' => 'Sat', 'dom' => 'Sun'], $monthTranslations));

        $meridianTranslations = [
            'a. m.' => 'am',
            'p. m.' => 'pm',
        ];

        $translatedDate = strtr($translatedDate, $meridianTranslations);

        return Carbon::createFromFormat('D. d M. Y, g:i:s a', $translatedDate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

Usage:

```
    echo getConvertDate('lun. 08 ene. 2024, 1:54:02 p. m.');
```